# Is it possible to extend prompt() object in JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, prompt

To make sure the question more clear,

I want to re-implement the prompt object in JAVASCRIPT because i want to get two variables from the user at the same time.

If it is possible to extend, re-implement or override this object, please tell me how. If not, do you have better solutions?

Thanks.

Comment: No, create your own dialog :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use something like http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form

You will need to split your javascript where you have your dialog

So if you had

```
function getAndUseUserInfo() {
   bla1();
   bla2();
   var x = prompt("Gimme something for bla 3","");
   if (x) bla3(x); // this will not be executed until user closes prompt
}
```

you now need

```
function getUserInfo() {
  bla1();
  bla2();
  var x = "";
  $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 300,
    width: 350,
    modal: true,
    buttons: { 
      "OK": function() { x = $("#someIdFromtheForm").val(); $(this).dialog("close");}
      "CANCEL": function() { $(this).dialog("close");}
    }
    close: function() {
      if (x) bla3(x);
    }
  });
}
```

Or if you insist to override the built-in function you can do something like this (which currently gives an error since I am not using an html page):

```
  var orgPrompt = window.prompt;
  var varone, vartwo;
  function saveVars(doc) {
    varone = doc.getElementById("x").value;
    vartwo = doc.getElementById("y").value
    return [varone,vartwo];
  }
  window.prompt=function(one,two) {
    var html = '<center><br><br>'+one+':<input type=text id=x><br>'+two+':<input type=text id=y><br><input type=button value=OK onclick=\'window.returnValue=window.dialogArguments.saveVars(document);window.close()\'/>';
    var res = showModalDialog('javascript:"'+html+'"',window,"dialogWidth:100px;dialogHeight:100px");
  }
  x = prompt('first name','last name')
  alert(x)
```

Comment: How is this suppose to work? How is `window.prompt` related to jQuer UI? I think it is not a good idea to override `window.prompt`.

Comment: window prompt is too large can i fix it? If i can how?

Comment: perfect :)
if you say how i can remove the address line i will be so appriciated

Comment: @Exculuber: Not possible unless you use the jQuery dialog or similar. Sorry

Comment: I've tried to use as you suggested the Jquery-ui dialog box. However, it doesn't pause javascript, but this solution pauses. How can i make dialog box to pause and resume javascript code, until the user reaction.

Answer (score 2):

You can have them separate the two different values using a delimiter.

```
var result = prompt('enter two values seperated by a comma').split(',');
alert('first value: ' + result[0]);
alert('second value: ' + result[1]);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wJ3sv/)**

Comment: thanks but this effects usability therefore i dont prefer this

Answer (score 1):

You can redefine most things in javascript, including the window prompt, alert and confirm methods, but it would probably be a better idea to define the method and call **it** instead of the native object. Define 'prompter','alerter' or 'confirmer' methods, for example.

Comment: i don't understand actually can you give an redefinement example for prompt